# How to use SignalR C++ client library with emscripten?

Tags: openssl, signalr, boost-asio, emscripten, cpprest-sdk

There are no problems with SignalR itself, but it are based on CPPRest. CPPRest is based on Boost-asio. Boost-asio needs OpenSSL libraries. For Boost-asio I can not use Boost libraries, if I build several cpp.

And at Visual Studio it works well. But I need to build this all under empscripten.

Is it possible?

Comment: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues/1015